# CSS / xpath selector to find h3 tag with text in a given class?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Selector to find a element with `<h3>` with some text which is a descendant of a class ?

Tried with `xpath="//*[@class='body']//descendant::h3[contains(text(), sampletext]`

This doesn't work. Is there a way I can find this ?

```
<div class="body">
  <h3> text1 </h3>
  <p>....</p>
  <h3> text2 </h3>
  <p>... </p>
  <h3> text3 </h3>
</div>
```

Selector to find `<h3>` tag containing text3 in `className="body"`?

Comment: Can you show us your work what you have tried still now?

Comment: Can you come with some details so we can analyze whats going on in your mind

Comment: Trying to find h3 tag with a specific text inside a class with multiple h3 tags.

Comment: Can you add the html code in question or can u share the site url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this simple xpath and let me know if facing any issue

```
//div[@class='body']/h3[text()='text3']
```

OR for trimming the spaces before and after your text

```
//div[@class='body']/h3[normalize-space()='text3']
```

Below to get the element bases on partial text match

```
//div[@class='body']/h3[contains(.,'text3')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed single quote `contains(text(), sampletext)]`

It should be `'sampletext'`

```
   xpath="//div[@class='body']//descendant::h3[contains(text(), 'sampletext')]"
```

if you want to find h3 tag

```
 xpath="//div[@class='body']/h3[contains(text(), 'text3')]"
```

Comment: and how about missing closing parenthesis?)